# Glitch in paging

Tags: bug

I am unable to navigate to page 2 of most voted JavaScript questions:

[image]

This also applies to other tabs such as newest, active and unanswered.

Does not happen if I am not logged in.

Note that when I am logged in and navigate to *home > popular tags > javascript > votes tab* the URL contains `?tab=votes`. But when I am not logged and follow the same path the URL contains `?sort=votes`:

[image]

Comment: Now someone can go head and say *"[We fixed the glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqjQDP9KX6E)"*...